# If I trade my Pokémon from Red to Gold on the VC, and then transfer it to Sun, what will be the Pokemon's original location?

Tags: pokemon-sun-moon, pokemon-red-blue-yellow-green, pokemon-gold-silver-crystal

On the 3DS, from the Virtual Console games, if I transfer a Kanto Pokémon from RBY to Sun/Moon it should appear that is from Kanto. If I transfer one from GSC to Sun/Moon it will appear that is from Johto, **but if I send one Pokémon from Red to Gold, will it still say that is from Kanto?**  (same if I send a Pokémon from Johto to Kanto, GSC to RBY).

Comment: Can you even do that with the VC games?

Comment: This is the kind of question where they complete step 1 and 2, then stop at 3 and see if someone else can do it for them

Comment: @JMac You can trade them between RBY to GSC, but i can't because i don't have a friend with the requeriments to try it.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I've been able to try this for you.  So I caught a Pidgey in Pokémon Red, I then transferred this to Pokémon Silver, then using the Poké Transporter / Bank I was able to move it to Moon (pictures below).  Unfortunately it doesn't say what region it was from, exactly.

> Of course one of the benefits of transporting Pokémon to Sun/Moon or
>   Ultra Sun/Ultra Moon is they instantly get 3 max IVs and Hidden
>   Ability.

Apologies for the low quality pictures, I was using my mobile phone and 3DS, and also for no picture of Red.

*Pidgey named STACKEXCH! caught in Red placed in Box 1 in Silver.*

[image]

*Pidgey transferred to Poké Bank via Poké Transporter*
[image]

*Pokémon moved within Poké Bank to Moon*
[image]

*And finally the summary page, which unfortunately doesn't say what region it came from, only that **"Seems to have traveled across both space and time to reach you from a distant land in the good old days"***  The Gameboy icon indicates it was from Gen 1/2 but isn't specific.

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much!!! This helps a lot so i won't be worried to transfer my old Bulbasaur to Gold and then make it lose his 'Kanto' status.
Thank you!